# Windows 7: Windows cover whole screen (including windows bar)

Tags: windows-7

All of the windows cover the whole screen when I maximize them.  For example, Chrome is covering the whole screen right now and I can't see the start button or task bar.  Usually they end at the windows bar at the bottom so I can still click on it.

I'm assuming I hit some sort of key combination for this to happen.  Does anyone know how to set this back to the default?

Comment: There's an option for this in Windows XP, but I don't see it for Windows 7.  Do you have auto-hide disabled?

Comment: On the task bar?  Yes.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to your desktop.
- Right-click on your taskbar.
- Click properties.
- Under Taskbar Appearance, uncheck "Auto-hide the taskbar".

Comment: Note comments on OP: "Do you have auto-hide disabled?" and "On the task bar? Yes."